# how to get "if suite" along with my "else suite"

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I have written these simple lines of code to get the current day name, and then using if/else statement wanted to check if it is the current day which is Sunday,and I should receive my *if suite* , because today is exactly Sunday, but the terminal gives me the *else suite*. I was wonder what is wrong with my code:

```
import datetime
now= datetime.datetime.now()
weeks=["Saturday","Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday"]
print ("Today is {}, So:".format(now.strftime("%A")))
if now in weeks:
    print("Gossh, You are now in your school days..")
else:
    print("rest and recover!")
```

and the result is:

```
Today is Sunday, So:
rest and recover!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are testing if `now` (a datetime object) is in `weeks` (string objects). `now` is not in `weeks`. No datetime object is in `weeks`

The formatted day name (`now.strftime("%A")`) might be, but you're not testing that.

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
dayname = now.strftime("%A")
weekdays = ["Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"]

print(f"Today is {dayname}, so:")
if dayname in weekdays:
    print("Gossh, You are now in your school days...")
else:
    print("rest and recover!")
```

That being said, both `weeks` and `weekdays` is a bad name for a variable that contains this particular list of day names. Find a better variable name.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for the edit. I wanted the OP to make that leap on their own, but spelling it out is also fine. :)

Comment: many thanks for the answer, I do agree we can change the variables into school days and day_name... thanks again.